# Unexpected output replacing words using dictionary and dic.iteritems - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
global dicnames

dicnames= {'co':'company' , 'svcs':'services' , 'hlth':'health' , 'equip':'equipment', 'corp':'corporation', 'intl':'international' }
```

I created this function to replace certain words in a string by their value in the dictionary:

```
def reemp(text):

    for i , j in dicnames.iteritems():
        text=text.replace(i,j)
    return text
```

It's working with all the words except 'corp'. For example:

```
 reemp('uni corp')

    Out[24]:
    'uni companyrp'
```

So . What's wrong in my code and How Can I fix that?

Comment: `co` is part of `corp`, and is getting replaced first.

Comment: That's because `co` is possibly changing all `corp` to `companyrp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) so that the replacements occur in the order you expect.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dicnames = OrderedDict([
    ('svcs', 'services'),
    ('hlth', 'health'),
    ('equip', 'equipment'),
    ('corp', 'corporation'),
    ('intl', 'international'),
    ('co', 'company'),
])

def reemp(text):
    for i , j in dicnames.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i,j)
    return text

print(reemp('uni corp'))
```

But even then you will have problems -- 'co' starts 'company' and 'corporation'. You will get multiple replacements. You need to rework `reemp` so that it does only a single replacement.

This will do a single replacement for you:

```
def reemp(text):
    for i , j in dicnames.iteritems():
        if i in text:
            return text.replace(i,j)
    return text
```

If you combine that with the `OrderedDict`, you should be able to work it out.